# How to select non blank cells in selected formula contain cell range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In G17 to G26 cells contain formulas like `=IF(Indent!$C17>0,Indent!$C$5,"")`
& as per formula we got result either C5 value or blank.
after selecting cell range (G17:G26), I want only C5 value cells in selected range without blank cell.

Note: Active Sheet name is Indent

As per my regular practice to find non blank cells from selected cells I select "Constant" in "Find & Select" tab but in this formula contain cell range it doesn't work. its shows "No Cells Were Found".

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column testing the contents. Then you could find / filter on TRUE / FALSE.
Please add file for further reference.

Comment: Actually I create one PDF/Word file for describing my issue with screen shot. which is easy for you to resolve that issue. but here no provision for uploading PDF/word file. now what I do?

Comment: It would be best to post the excel file (delete for your eyes only data first)  Edit: You could upload your file to www.filedropper.com and share the link.

Comment: Thanks for support.Actually my requirement is different regarding auto update cells. in the time of making the same,I face above mentioned issue. please find below file for what I Want.....http://www.filedropper.com/requiredautoupdatecell                      & another below file which I want to edit.......http://www.filedropper.com/indentsample

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
=IF(AND(Indent!$C17>0,Indent!$C17<>""),Indent!$C$5,"")
```